# How to setup an aerospike cluster with a single node?

Tags: aerospike

I currently have a working cluster with two nodes. Following is the content of `/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf` -

```
network {
    service {
        address any
        port 3000
    }
    heartbeat {
        mode mesh
        port 3002 # Heartbeat port for this node.
        # List one or more other nodes, one ip-address & port per line:

                mesh-seed-address-port <existing server's ip> 3002

                mesh-seed-address-port <other server's ip> 3002


        interval 250
        timeout 10
    }
    fabric {
        port 3001
    }
    info {
        port 3003
    }
}
```

I tried by changing the heartbeat setting by removing the address port of the other node -

```
heartbeat {
            mode mesh
            port 3002 # Heartbeat port for this node.
            # List one or more other nodes, one ip-address & port per line:

                    mesh-seed-address-port <existing server's ip> 3002

            interval 250
            timeout 10
        }
```

Then I restarted the aerospike and the amc services -

```
service aerospike restart
service amc restart
```

However, still the `/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log` file shows two nodes present -

```
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:249)    system-memory: free-kbytes 125756260 free-pct 99 heap-kbytes (2343074,2344032,2417664) heap-efficiency-pct 96.9
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:263)    in-progress: tsvc-q 0 info-q 0 nsup-delete-q 0 rw-hash 0 proxy-hash 0 tree-gc-q 0
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:285)    fds: proto (20,23,3) heartbeat (1,1,0) fabric (19,19,0)
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:294)    heartbeat-received: self 0 foreign 1488
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:348) {FC} objects: all 0 master 0 prole 0
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:409) {FC} migrations: complete
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:428) {FC} memory-usage: total-bytes 0 index-bytes 0 sindex-bytes 0 data-bytes 0 used-pct 0.00
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:348) {TARGETPARAMS} objects: all 0 master 0 prole 0
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:409) {TARGETPARAMS} migrations: complete
Mar 07 2017 13:16:28 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:428) {TARGETPARAMS} memory-usage: total-bytes 0 index-bytes 0 sindex-bytes 0 data-bytes 0 used-pct 0.00
Mar 07 2017 13:16:38 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:169) NODE-ID bb93c00b70b0022 CLUSTER-SIZE 2
Mar 07 2017 13:16:38 GMT: INFO (info): (ticker.c:249)    system-memory: free-kbytes 125756196 free-pct 99 heap-kbytes (2343073,2344032,2417664) heap-efficiency-pct 96.9
```

So does the AMC console.

Comment: By the way, how to check the version of aerospike? Unable to find the command.

Comment: asinfo -h "HOST.IP" -v "version"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help: http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/cluster_mng/removing_node

Once the node is removed properly, you can restart it with the different heartbeat config so that it doesn't join the other node.

For version, simply do `asd --version`. You can also use `asinfo -v build`.

The version is also printed within asadm / AMC and in the logs right at startup.